# Is the Lie derivative of a harmonic form also a harmonic form?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, lie-derivative

On Helgason's book "Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces" it is said that the Lie derivative of an harmonic form is again a harmonic form. This affirmation is on the compact Lie group case, with bi-invariant Riemmanian metric. I have some questions:

How can I prove this statement? Do you have a reference? Should I try first to prove that the codifferential(the adjoint of the exterior derivative) commutes with the Lie derivative?

Does it hold in general? That is, if I have a complete Riemannian manifold, does it hold that the Lie derivative of a harmonic form is again a harmonic form?

Can you suggest some references?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Part II (page 40) of [This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=ykEZ5z5-5x8C&lpg=PA49&dq=Lie%20derivative%20of%20an%20harmonic%20form%20is%20again%20a%20harmonic%20form&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false) of  *Kentaro Yano, Salomon Bochner* would be 
useful

*Curvature and Betti Numbers, K. Yano, S. Bochner.*